# How is $\lim p_n(x) = 0$?

Tags: limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

I came across this example in Hogg, Craig's Mathematical Statistics Book:
[image]

They mention "Clearly, $\lim p_n(x) = 0$." I don't understand why this is true. Isn't it the case that as $n \rightarrow \infty$, $\lim x = 2+0 = 2$? Thanks!

Comment: You are mixing $x$ and $n$. What they state is true. Indeed, take any $x$, say $x = 2 + 100^{-1}$. What is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} p_n(x)$?

Comment: Try to use the definition of limit to show.

Answer (score 3):

$p_n(x)$ is always either $1$ or $0$, so $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}p_n(x)$ cannot possibly be $2$: if it exists at all, it must be either $1$ or $0$. In this case we are holding $x$ fixed and considering what happens to $p_n(x)$ as $n$ increases without bound. There is at most one $n$ such that $2+\frac1n=x$; if it exists, call it $n_0$. If it does not exist, then $p_n(x)=0$ for all $n$, and if it does exist, $p_n(x)=0$ for all $n>n_0$; in either case $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}p_n(x)=0$.